# Javascript: Cross Domain AJAX to 3rd party service

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, iframe, cross-domain

Yeah I know, pretty popular question. But I still can't make a comprehensive picture of browser Javascript possibilities for my needs.

**I want:** to make a Cross Domain request from browser to 3rd party service which doesn't support CORS, JSONP, easyXDM and another stuff that could make my life easier. And I haven't got any access to that service.

**For instance:** I want to [download this audio](http://cs7-4v4.vk-cdn.net/p7/223f8c4d0551b8.mp3?extra=TzSZ-GFQXaL4ELIwKontKM8GRYGP64zZnZpqFMPjFt_BD1n_1_AwkWamqkNorDumCeHOFSraQGmejZu3-bP6wndGguRlyaXR).

**Important:** of course, I can write my own proxy server, but that means to work with hight load and data storage problem => more headache

**Questions:**

- Is it possible via *postMessage*? If I will open target url in hidden window/popup and will do *postMessage* between them?
- Is that possible via *window.name Transport*? How?
- Is it possible via iFrames? How?
- Is it possible with Flash? How?

**My investigations: [optional section]** Ways to do Cross Domain Request:

1. ***postMessage*** - only suitable for communication between different windows
2. ***JSONP*** - not suitable in my case - needs server JSONP support
3. ***CORS*** - not suitable in my case - needs server CORS support
4. ***document.domain methods*** - only suitable for 2 different servers on the same domain (not my case)
5. ***window.name Transport*** - not sure what it is
6. ***CRAZY IFRAME STUFF*** - as I understand it only possible if 3rd party service also had iFrame which wants to communicate with my iFrame (not suitable because I haven't access to target service)
7. ***flash*** - *is that possible?*
8. ***Server-side proxy*** - I don't want headache with hight load and Cloud Services, so I hope to move all functionality to client side. So proxy is my last option.